Streaming Axis video to Dolby using WebRTC WHIP protocol
I'm trying to streaming my Axis video feed to Dolby using WHIP protocol. I copied the gstreamer pipeline from this document https://docs.dolby.io/streaming-apis/docs/using-whip-with-gstreamer#publishing-an-rtsp-video-only-source. I used the exact same pipeline as the one in the doc.
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location="rtsp://192.168.1.168/0" latency=0 name=rtsp ! \
  rtph264depay ! rtph264pay config-interval=-1 ! \
  application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264 ! \
  whipsink name=whip auth-token=$DOLBYIO_BEARER_TOKEN \
  whip-endpoint=$DOLBYIO_WHIP_ENDPOINT

I could see some data at Dolby's dashboard such as FPS and package lost etc, but the video is still black, cannot see anything. The location, token and endpoint are correct, the camera itself is also working.
I couldn't use the "simple-whip-client" as mentioned in the document because it requires the ubuntu version to be 22.04, mine is 20.04 and we cannot upgrade it to 22.04.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!
